# How does the Nova's Burn power work at the 7-9 level?

Tags: powers, powered-by-the-apocalypse, masks-a-new-generation

In *Masks*, Novas have the Burn power:

> #### Burn
>
> When you charge up your powers, roll + conditions you currently have marked. On a hit, hold 3 burn. On a 7-9, mark a condition. On a miss, hold 2 burn and mark three conditions.
>
> Spend your burn on your flares. You lose all burn at the end of the scene.
>
> Choose four flares.

This is a power that Novas, a core class have. They can get this resource and spend it to do fun things, like pick up buildings,

How does this power work on the 7-9 segment? Do you hold 2 burn as well? Do you hold 3 burn, since if it's a hit you hold 3? Do you hold no burn for the 7-9 segment? I am really not sure what the intended experience for Novas is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any result of 7 or higher is a hit.  On a 7-9, the Nova holds 3 burns and marks a condition.

There are quite a few moves in Masks that use this basic phrasing:  On a hit, something happens; on a 7-9, something else happens.  When phrased this way, the "something else" is always in addition to the "something".  (It would probably be a bit clearer if they always wrote "also" in the 7-9 portion.)

By contrast, other moves use the simpler phrasing: On a 10+, something happens; on a 7-9, something else happens.  When written this way, the two results are mutually exclusive.